# Python `tempfile.gettempdir()` does not respect TMPDIR

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am using a shared linux cluster and want my temporary directory to be `/tmp/username` rather than the default `/tmp`.

According to the [`tempfile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir), `gettempdir()` should use the `$TMPDIR` environment variable to determine the temporary directory.

However, this does not seem to be the case?!

```
$ export TMPDIR='/tmp/username' 
$ python -c "\
import os
import tempfile
print(os.environ['TMPDIR'])
print(tempfile.gettempdir())"
/tmp/username
/tmp
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the directory exist?  Is it writable by the user?  If not, it won't work and Python will fallback to other locations.  You can see the code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/tempfile.py#l176), reproduced here for reference:

```
def _get_default_tempdir():
    """Calculate the default directory to use for temporary files.
    This routine should be called exactly once.

    We determine whether or not a candidate temp dir is usable by
    trying to create and write to a file in that directory.  If this
    is successful, the test file is deleted.  To prevent denial of
    service, the name of the test file must be randomized."""

    namer = _RandomNameSequence()
    dirlist = _candidate_tempdir_list()
    flags = _text_openflags

    for dir in dirlist:
        if dir != _os.curdir:
            dir = _os.path.normcase(_os.path.abspath(dir))
        # Try only a few names per directory.
        for seq in xrange(100):
            name = namer.next()
            filename = _os.path.join(dir, name)
            try:
                fd = _os.open(filename, flags, 0o600)
                try:
                    try:
                        with _io.open(fd, 'wb', closefd=False) as fp:
                            fp.write(b'blat')
                    finally:
                        _os.close(fd)
                finally:
                    _os.unlink(filename)
                return dir
            except (OSError, IOError) as e:
                if e.args[0] == _errno.EEXIST:
                    continue
                if (_os.name == 'nt' and e.args[0] == _errno.EACCES and
                    _os.path.isdir(dir) and _os.access(dir, _os.W_OK)):
                    # On windows, when a directory with the chosen name already
                    # exists, EACCES error code is returned instead of EEXIST.
                    continue
                break # no point trying more names in this directory
    raise IOError, (_errno.ENOENT,
                    ("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
```

Comment: Good catch. I opened an issue at Python's bugtracker to improve the documentation: https://bugs.python.org/issue27023